# Best practices, loading model objects from database

Tags: c#

I've got the following model class:

```
public class Product
{
  public int ProductID {get;set;}
  public string ProductName {get;set; ]
  public int ActiveOrdersCount {get;set;}
  public Category[] Categories {get;set}
     //etc...
}
```

When I load a product from the database, I load all the properties and maybe lazy-load the categories.

Does it make more sense to load all the properties of the object or partial etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how the objects will be accessed at run time.  If you want to immediately access the categories collection for all of the products in a collection, then lazy loading will be very chatty.

On the other end of the spectrum if you only want to hit the Categories property for a small subset of the returned values, lazy loading might be beneficial.